# How bad is this commutator pitting?

Tags: motor, arc, spark

I'll try to post an image but I think there is some pitting on one of the bars of the commutator and was wondering how bad it was and if it can be fixed.You can see the right side brush looks pretty bad, it still has good length and the spring seems strong.[image]

Comment: There are several reasons you see wear like this on high speed AC/DC motors. 1) Bad bearings and a slightly unbalanced armature 2) Commutator not round or central on shaft 3) Carbon buildup between segments (consumes the copper segment) Short answer, buy a new tool as this one will eventually fail. If there is enough brush pressure then new brushes won't help.

Comment: Heey, Sorry for the necropost, but i had the same thing, which turned out to be dust between the carbon and the socket. which blocked the working of the spring, so there was no more pressure.